Circle Method applications only for Quadratic & Cubic Form
So I have studied multiple applications of Circle Method.
1- Initially I read about the Classical Hardy Littlewood circle method, where they use generating functions, and determine hte coefficent using integration over $[0,1]$. Further they divide the interval $[0,1]$ into major arc and minor arc. They estimate the integral over minor arc which is dominated by the major arcs.
2- There is another form of circle method which was developed by Heath Brown[1]. They express $\delta_n$ as summation of some nice smooth functions. They use it to get an expression for the number of solutions to a quadratic equation inside the box $[-P,P]^n$.
My question is why these methods fails for Quartic Equations. I got to learn that these methods are not helpful when one deals with homogenous forms of higher degree(Degree $\geq 4$). They mention that they used poisson summation formula while they derived an expression of $N(F,w)$. I am still not sure despite spending a lot of time on it. Can anyone help me understand this?
Heath-Brown, D. R., A new form of the circle method, and its application to quadratic forms, J. Reine Angew. Math. 481, 149-206 (1996). ZBL0857.11049..
